# Creating Excel document using JavaScript

Tags: 2010, javascript, excel

I've been researching into creating Excel documents in a SharePoint Library from an existing Excel template but all solutions I find are using server code. 
The Template can be part of a CT or in another Library.

I believe it can be achieved with JavaScript Object Model (jsom). Does anyone know how?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is a SharePoint related question. Since you had not mentioned anywhere 'SharePoint' in question or at least in tags. Please clarify if your excel document is residing in SharePoint library or else where?

Comment: Sorry, just Updated Question

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ExcelPlus](https://aymkdn.github.io/ExcelPlus/) that permits to deal with Excel in JS and its based on [xls-js](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) ... I created it while working on [SharepointPlus](https://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/), a JS library for Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt about doing this with a excel template but yes there is way to do excel with JSOM it involes of Excel Web Access webparts [Check here](http://blogs.office.com/2009/11/30/introducing-the-javascript-object-model-for-excel-services-in-sharepoint-2010/) for more details

Comment: How about copying an exel document from one library to another with a different name and different column settings ?